# Find $e^{AT}$ where $A$ is a Matrix that is given

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the value of  $e^{At}$ where

$A$ is the matrix

$A =\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Hint: the matrix is diagonalizable, find the Jordan Normal Form and write $e^{At} = P e^{Jt} P^{-1}$.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but should that be $e^{Jt}$?

Comment: Are you aware that $e^A=I+A+\frac{1}{2!}A^2+...$?

Comment: @BlackAdder Yes i know the expansion of $e^x$ for that i have to find $A^2$ , $A^3$ so on...??

Comment: @Amzoti I don't understand how do we get that form for $e^At$??

Comment: Another method .... $e^{At}$ is solution(Fundamental matrix ) of  $X’=AX$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: This is a diagonalizable matrix and here are the steps:

1. Find the eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$
2. Find the eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$
3. Write $J = P^{-1}AP$, where $P = [v_1 | v_2]$. You will get $J$ is a diagonal matrix made up of the two eigenvalues.
4. Write $e^{At} = P e^{Jt} P^{-1}$. The exponential of $e^{Jt}$ is just made up of $e^{\lambda_1 t}$ and $e^{\lambda_2t}$.

Note that there are many other ways to find a matrix exponential.